# AngularJS and ui-view causing infinite recursion

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, angular-ui

I am building an AngularJS application on top of Ruby on Rails 4. So far, I've just pieced together the basics. Here's a trivial config/routes.rb:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  root :to => 'home#index'

  namespace :api do
  end

  get '*a', to: 'home#index' 

end
```

I have a trivial `application.html.erb` layout and it is tagged up for AngularJS with this excerpt:

```
<html ng-app="MyApp" ng-init="current_user = <%= current_user.to_json %>;">
```

On Angular's side, I have a simple route setup using ui-router:

```
MyApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

      $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                templateUrl: 'index.html.erb' })


      // For any unmatched url
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
});
```

Now, if I don't put any markup into `app/views/home/index.html.erb`, there is no infinite recursion problem. The moment I add this into it, the app just completely explodes:

`<div ui-view></div>`

I'm not sure how to bootstrap my app with a `ui-view` container so AngularJS can populate the rest of the templating. Not entirely sure what's causing this infinite recursion. Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, Angularjs doesn't support multiple `ng-view` directives.

So the correct way is to  put `<div ui-view></div>` in the root html `application.html.erb`, and `index.html.erb` will be rendered in the `ui-view` of the root html template.

Comment: But does that application.html.erb get served by the default Ruby on Rails layout, or is this a template served by AngularJS? Confused how this would work. None of the sample apps I've seen are fully functional.

Comment: Angularjs has self-contained MVC with routing. So you only need a "plain" web server. If you use any template engine, you should only let the view engine to render the root html, and for other partial pages, the routing should be handled by pure angularjs. Hope it helps.

Comment: But that's exactly what Rails is serving, the "root" html, in this case, application.html.erb. That has to have <div ui-view> markup in it otherwise AngularJS won't know how to work with it.

Comment: The infinite loop is caused by angularjs when you put a <ui-view> in a partial which will be rendered in the <ui-view> in your root html page.

Answer (score 1):

Just had a similar issue with a slightly different cause: a missing template in my routeProvider. But instead of throwing an error the .htaccess caused the index.html to be served, resulting in infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a different root cause. For me, I had enabled HTML5 mode by setting `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` while also setting a catch-all `get '*path', to: 'application#index'` in my routes.rb, where `application#index` was the same template that contained my `<div ui-view></div>` element. Whereas before, angular was namespacing routes in the URL with a hashtag, it is no longer the case in html 5 mode, so when the ui-view attempted to get its template, from `/` (formerly `#/`), it was overridden by Rails due to `get '*a', to: 'home#index'` and so the entire initial Rails template was reloaded under the ui-view.

I was using angular-rails-templates, and found I still need to prefix by `templateUrl`s with `/assets/`, e.g. `templateUrl: /assets/myTemplate.html`